# Get a specific string from a file

Tags: bash, sed, cat

I have a file that begins with this kind of format

```
INFO|NOT-CLONED|/folder/another-folder/another-folder2|last-folder-name|
```

What I need is to read the file and get this output:

```
another-folder
```

I have this so far:

```
sed -En 's/(INFO\|NOT-CLONED\|).*\|([^|]*)\|$/\1\2/p'"
```

But is not working as intended.

Comment: If you need to output `another-folder`, you should try `echo another-folder`.  This question fails to describe what it is you actually want.  Do you want the 2nd portion of a path in the 3rd column of a `|` delimited file?  Or do you want the penultimate portion of the same path? Or do you want all but the last character of the last element of the path?   Or do you want the 3rd column of a `/` delimited file?  or do you want some munged version of the 2nd field of an `a` delimited file?  You cannot merely describe the actual output you want.  You have to describe how you get that output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'/' '/INFO\|NOT-CLONED/{print $3}' file
```

Or if you want it using `sed` :

```
sed  -n 's@INFO|NOT-CLONED|/[^/]\+/\([^/]\+\).*@\1@gp' file
```